# How to display data for particular username from database?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

On my index page are displayed different users. What i want to achieve is when someone click on the username to be redirected on other page where are displayed informations for the user.
Here is part of the twig code which will redirect the user to the hello route.

```
{% for user in users %}
<strong><em><a href="{{ path('hello') }}"> {{ user.username}}</a>
```

And this is hello route :

```
hello:
pattern: /hello
defaults: {_controller:AcmeWebBundle:Default:hello }
```

I have no idea how to implement this in the contoroler. Can i use variable in which are stored informations for the users from other function or i need to make db query? And how that query to be for particular user who is displayed? In addition is part from the entity. Thanks.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\WebBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * baza
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class baza
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="od", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $od;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="do", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $do;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cena", type="float")
     */
    private $cena;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="text")
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rating", type="integer")
     */
    private $rating;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="car", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $car;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your template:

```
{% for user in users %}
<strong><em><a href="{{ path('hello', {"id": user.id}</a>
```

and this in your routing:

```
hello:
pattern: /hello/{id}
```

and your controller will have something like:

```
public function helloAction(Request $request, $id)
```

then in your controller retrieve the user by id.  This and the rest of it is can be inferred in the [book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you geoB. This help me, but im still confused .. how to get the id from twig to the controler and than pass it to the database in order to get informations for that user?

Comment: @C0ld: The link contains the user id as a parameter for the route `/hello`.  The controller for the hello action will get that as parameter passed as shown above.  In the controller you'll call the entity manager and use it to `...->find($id)` on the user entity.  Forgive me for not providing the code explicitly - as a former professor I prefer to have students learn by doing rather than by copying me.  hth

Comment: It's ok @geoB, im just begginer maybe thats why i didnt understand your initial answer.Thank you for your help.

Comment: @C0ld: I recently went thru the beginner stage with Symfony.  The learning curve is steep.  But the best way to go about it is to take small steps and follow the Book and the Cookbook.  It will come.  It just takes time.